# Configuring XML source in SSIS Project deployment method

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012

I am working on the deployment and configuration of an SSIS project deployment package (SQL 2012). The package reads data from an XML.

In the data flow task XML Source does not have an Expressions property that I could easily use to configure the source file path using a parameter, nor does it take an XML file connection.

In the package deployment I used to be able to set any property value using the config file as a workaround; it looked like this:

```html
<Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package\Preparation and Staging\Load data into Staging table.Properties[[XML Source].[XMLData]]" ValueType="String">
  <ConfiguredValue>D:\Folder\SourceFile.xml</ConfiguredValue>
</Configuration>
```

Is there any way to achieve this when in project deployment method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, XML Source does have a property for specifying XML Source. Two pictures instead of 100 words.
[image: XML Source Properties]
[image: Properties of DataFlow]
Red rectangle shows properties you can use for dynamic configuration of XML Source. These properties have corresponding Expressions.
[image: XML Source Expressions]

Comment: Your post does not address the question. Thanks for the images but what I wanted to point out cannot be shown because it does not exist.

Comment: @LasloKatai-Pal, you can define special variable for XML file path another - for XML filename and define XMLData property as an expression `[User::XML_FilePath] + "\\" + [User::XML_FileName]`. Or you can use a Package or Project property in the expression as `[$Package::XML_Path] +...`. Just use expressions with its full capability.

Comment: As I indicated in my original question "XML Source does not have an Expressions property". I cannot add in a project parameter there.

Comment: @LasloKatai-Pal, you are right, XML Source itself does not have any Expressions property. **But** *[<XML Source Name.].[XMLData]* and *.[XMLSchemaDefinition]* properties are exposed at DataFlow task where XML Source is used. So you can configure it there with the expressions.

Comment: That worked! I overlooked the tiny detail that the scope is the DataFlow task! Thank you.